# Dynamic login using boto3 and using other boto3 components (ie resource)?

Tags: boto3

I'm trying to make a class that would login using the client component of boto3 and then use resource class. How would I go from boto3.client to boto3.resource by manually supplying the access_key_id and secret_access_key? I am unable store any credentials in a config file. It'll be passed into through a database.

```
self.client = boto3.client(
              's3',
              aws_access_key_id=access_key_id,
              aws_secret_access_key=secret_access_key,
          )
```

If I wanted to use any other boto3 classes, what would I have to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to create a Session first and then use the Session to create the Resource.

```
import boto3

session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id="<foo>",
                        aws_secret_access_key="<bar>")
s3 = session.resource('s3')
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I'm looking for.